# making a typedef local to a file or subclasses

Tags: c++, class, scope, typedef

I'm consolidating 2 programs into one, and in 2 different files (I have many files), I have a typedef with the same name, different types though.

These types will be used in completely different parts of the program and will never talk to each other, or be used interachangely.

I can of cause just do a search replace in one of the files, but I was wondering if there is another solution to this.

Something like binding a typedef to a specific file.
Or making a typedef local to a class and it's subclasses.

Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest could be just to rename the typedef manually.

Comment: Thats what [namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) are for.

Comment: The original authors should have used namespaces. That's what they are for. And as you see now, "My program is small enough that I do not need namespaces" is no excuse for not using namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encapsulate those `typedef` inside a `namespace`:

```
namespace N1 {
  typedef int T;
}
namespace N2 {
  typedef int T;
}
```

And in whatever file you want to use first `typedef` simply declare:

```
using namespace N1;
```

same thing for the other one also.

Answer (score 7):

`typedef`s are *always* "local to a file". So it is not exactly clear what you mean by "making it local to a file". Typedef does not introduce an entity with its own linkage, it simply creates an alias to an existing type. For that reason the problem of "making it local to a file" simply does not exist. Each typedef is only visible in the translation unit (file) in which it is declared. So, if you can make sure that your identically named `typedef`s never meet each other in a common translation unit, you problem is formally solved.

It is not a good programming practice though to have the same typedef-name refer to different types in different files, unless these files are naturally separated somehow (like belong to different libraries, or something like that).

Otherwise, you can always rename one of the `typedef`s, or make it a class member or a namespace member. Keep in mind though that in general case the making a `typedef` member of a class will require virtually the same kind of effort as renaming it: the references to that `typedef` will have to be updated in every place in which they are present. Namespaces might be a bit easier, since with namespaces you can use `using` directive.

But again, if your `typedef`s are only referrd from two disjoint sets of files, then the problem does not formally exist. If there are files that are supposed to use both `typedef`s, then the effort you'll have to spend fixing these files will be equivalent to renaming the `typedef`s (regardless of the method you finally choose).

Comment: If a `typedef` is in a header file which is included everywhere then it will not be local to the file.

Comment: Translation unit might include more than one file, if the typedef is in a header, it will be "global" to all files that include that header. That being said, if they are, as the question states, completely independent pieces of code, they should not share the includes. +1

Comment: @iammilind: It will be local to each file into which it is included. And each file will have its own independent `typedef`. So, it is up to the author of the code to decide where to include that `typedef` and where not to include. If the `typedef` is used, it has to be included. If it is not used, it doesn't have to be included. There's no room here for any "making it local to a file". There's simply no such concept as "making `typedef` local to a file" in C++.

Answer (score 2):

> [...]Or making a typedef local to a class
>   and it's subclasses.

Well, that's simple:

```
struct A
{
 typedef int X;
}; 

struct B : A 
{ 
 X a; 
}; 

struct C
{
 typedef double X;
};
```

Typedefs are scoped in C++.